# TNote 10yr Futures YTM vs market yield?

Tags: united-states, bonds, futures, yield, treasury

I understand how to calculate the yield on a 10 yr TNote based on face, price & coupon.

I don’t understand why the yield (and price) on a futures contract about to expire is so different than the market yield (and price) if you buy a note instead.

For example March 21 10 Yr TNote contracts are about 131 which (I think) gives a yield of 2.48% but the notes auctioned last week had a yield of about 1.5%.

I understand the future is based on 6% coupon and e.g. last weeks auction had a coupon of 1.125% but I can’t see how this is reflected in the contract price.

If my data is correct(?) I don’t see why you wouldn’t buy the note, sell the future & pocket the difference?

Thanks for any help

EDIT 1:
This question was answered in the Quantitative Finance group ([TNote Futures contract YTM vs yield on bought notes?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61712/tnote-futures-contract-ytm-vs-yield-on-bought-notes)) - key information was suggestion to look at:
https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html

This question is now answered

Answer (score -1):

This question was answered in the Quantitative Finance group - key information was suggestion to look at:
https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html